# What are the way to sed a udp packet to openvpn

Tags: c#, .net, udp, openvpn

Considering that openvpn is a udp server running on port 1194, I am intrested to see  , how can I send a packet using udp c#.

I am aware of the fact that openVpn is a protocol itself, and considering the lack of knowledge in that domain , I started writing a simple udp client to send a message to server.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConnectOpenVPN
{

    public struct Received
    {
        public IPEndPoint Sender;
        public string Message;
    }

    abstract class UdpBase
    {
        protected UdpClient Client;

        protected UdpBase()
        {
            Client = new UdpClient();
        }

        public async Task<Received> Receive()
        {
            var result = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
            return new Received()
            {
                Message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length),
                Sender = result.RemoteEndPoint
            };
        }
    }


    //Client
    class UdpUser : UdpBase
    {
        private UdpUser() { }

        public static UdpUser ConnectTo(IPAddress serverIP, int port)
        {
            var connection = new UdpUser();
            connection.Client.Connect(serverIP, port);
            return connection;
        }

        public void Send(string message)
        {
            var datagram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            Client.Send(datagram, datagram.Length);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //create a new client
            var client = UdpUser.ConnectTo(IPAddress.Parse("13.23.118.17"), 1194);


            Task.Run(async () => {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var received = await client.Receive();
                        Console.WriteLine(received.Message);
                        if (received.Message.Contains("quit"))
                            break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            });

            string read;
            do
            {
                read = Console.ReadLine();
                client.Send(read);
            } while (read != "quit");
        }
    }
}
```

So , I am unable to recieve any message from server and just witing for ever. Not even an denied or exception.

I was planning to send credentials and openvpn config next.

What are the thing I should do when creating client program for open vpn client ? Is creating an UDP client even correct or I should be using openVPn protocol itseld and how?

Comment: You need an IP and port number which can be set in the UdpClient(address, port) constructor

Comment: @jdweng, I am doing that on UdpUser.ConnectTo(IPAddress.Parse("13.23.118.17"), 1194); It's  just a wrapper on UdpClient using UdpBase. Not just accepting the IP  and port with constructor but on connect.

Comment: Are you getting to the read code?  With all your async and await I can't tell where the code is stopping.  Use good debug techniques and first find where you code is running.  A easy thing to do is to use the menu debug.BreakAll and then step though code using F11.  Second make sure your server really sent a message.  You will not receive a message unless the server send one.